# .bashrc: Permission denied

Tags: bash, ssh, vagrant, permission-denied, nupic

I try to work with a project in vagrant. 
I have made the command `vagrant ssh`, and connected to VM. Now I need to edit `.bashrc` file to set path to the source code. But first I couldn't find that file. So I googled and find that the way is call command `~/.bashrc`. But doing this I get message, that I have no access to it:

```
[vagrant@nupic-vagrant:~]$ ~/.bashrc
-bash: /home/vagrant/.bashrc: Permission denied
```

So what to do now?

UPD.
I can't find the .bashrc file.
When I try to make command `ls -a` I get following:

```
[vagrant@nupic-vagrant:~]$ ls -a
.              .bash_logout   cleanup.sh   sshd.sh        .veewee_params
..             .bash_profile  minimize.sh  vagrant.sh     .veewee_version
.bash_history  .bashrc        .ssh         .vbox_version  .zsh_profile
[vagrant@nupic-vagrant:~]$ locate .bashrc
/etc/skel/.bashrc
/home/vagrant/.bashrc
/var/chef/backup/etc/skel/.bashrc.chef-20130614181911
/var/chef/backup/home/vagrant/.bashrc.chef-20130614181912
[vagrant@nupic-vagrant:~]$
```

But only the place where I can find some of those files is the directory where cygwin is installed. Pls, see illustrations, they reflect relations between directories vagrant and cygwin.
[image]

Answer (score 44):

`.bashrc` is not meant to be executed but sourced. Try this instead:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

or, equivalently

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

See the reference about the [`.`](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) (aka [`source`](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#index-source)) builtin.

---

Note that if what you're looking for is to restart your Bash session after modifying your `~/.bashrc` file, you might as well use:

```
exec bash
```

That will *replace* your current Bash session (thanks to [`exec`](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#index-exec)) by a new session.

Comment: I did it, but seems that happend nothing. Just shows me next input: **[vagrant@nupic-vagrant:~]$ ** so how to get it edited?

Comment: @srgg6701 Nothing _seems_ to happen, but it was sourced! To edit it, errr, just edit it with your favorite editor. If you like `vim`, just do `vim ~/.bashrc` if you like `nano` just do `nano ~/.bashrc` and if you like `ed`, you probably know what to do `:)`.

Comment: Yes, it looks very stupid, I know. But I never worked with vagrant, linux env etc. I never faced situation when a file exists but I can edit it only after running some text editor from command line. Pls, consider that I worked only on Windows. I have some editors here like notepad++ but have no idea how to use it in command line. Should I set a path variable to make it possible?

Comment: @srgg6701 It's just a regular file, edit it with the editor you like best! you don't need any command line at all to edit it. Just locate it in you explorer and edit it.

Comment: I can't see that file (.bashrc). I checked whole vagrant directory. Or it may be somewhere else? If I try command ls (or dir) it shows me only those: cleanup.sh  minimize.sh  sshd.sh  vagrant.sh

Comment: @srgg6701 In a linux environment, you'd need `ls -a` to show hidden files. You could also `locate .bashrc`. But very likely, `.bashrc` is located in user's home dir: `cd; ls -a` should get you there and show you the file.

Answer (score 25):

If you want to edit that file (or any file in generally), you can't edit it simply writing its name in terminal. You must to use a command to a text editor to do this. For example:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

And in general, for any type of file:

```
xdg-open ~/.bashrc
```

Writing only `~/.bashrc` in terminal, this will try to execute that file, but `.bashrc` file is not meant to be an executable file. If you want to execute the code inside of it, you can source it like follow:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or simple:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: I have no nano/gedit. And my OS is windows. If understand right this can work if those editors' paths are set in env path variables? Or there is some another way to reach result?

Comment: both of command that you pointed out lead to nothing - it just shows me the next input line.

Comment: Try `xdg-open ~/.bashrc`. ...You should have an text editor installed.

Comment: [vagrant@nupic-vagrant:~]$ . ~/.bashrc

[vagrant@nupic-vagrant:~]$ xdg-open ~/.bashrc

/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 402: htmlview: command not found

/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 402: firefox: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 402: mozilla: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 402: netscape: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 402: links: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 402: lynx: command not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening '/home/vagrant/.bashrc'

Comment: @srgg6701 What about: `nano ~/.bashrc` or `vi ~/.bashrc` or `vim ~/.bashrc` or `ed ~/.bashrc` or `joe ~/.bashrc` or `pico ~/.bashrc`... Ther should be one editor installed. If not, try to install one.

Comment: [vagrant@nupic-vagrant:~]$ ed ~/.bashrc

Newline appended

464

Answer (score 11):

If you can't access the file and your os is any linux distro or mac os x then either of these commands should work:

```
sudo nano .bashrc

chmod 777 .bashrc
```

it is worthless

Answer (score 0):

The .bashrc file is in your user home directory (~/.bashrc or ~vagrant/.bashrc both resolve to the same path), *inside the VM's filesystem*. This file is invisible on the host machine, so you can't use any Windows editors to edit it directly.

You have two simple choices:

1. Learn how to use a console-based text editor. My favourite is vi (or vim), which takes 15 minutes to learn the basics and is much quicker for simple edits than anything else.

   vi .bashrc
2. Copy .bashrc out to /vagrant (which is a shared directory) and edit it using your Windows editors. Make sure not to save it back with any extensions.

   cp .bashrc /vagrant
   ... edit using your host machine ...
   cp /vagrant/.bashrc .

I'd recommend getting to know the command-line based editors. Once you're working inside the VM, it's best to stay there as otherwise you might just get confused.

You (the vagrant user) are the owner of your home .bashrc so you do have permissions to edit it.

Once edited, you can execute it by typing 
    source .bashrc
I prefer to logout and in again (there may be more than one file executed on login).

Answer (score 0):

Please find the step to fix bash restricted error on Linux servers.

If you are getting below restricted message while try to login to the server by using your credentials , then it might be an issue with lack of directory permissions in the server.

Because of this permission issue we were unable to navigate to required directories and getting error “bash: cd: restricted”

Fix : To release bash restriction error use the highlighted command in Linux server -bash -f

As same if wants to restrict the permission use the highlighted command - bash -r

Once you executed the bash -f command the restrictions will be released from the directories and we can able to proceed with patch scripts.

Answer (score 0):

There all your nvm already installed.
please check on the current bash you are on and rename it and make sure you use that bash(terminal).[image: Please detail here]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).