# I have downloaded pig but it is not working

Tags: apache-pig

I have installed Pig. But when I am running command to check pig version. It is saying invalid option. I have edited bashrc file.

After doing source .bashrc I am getting following error:

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ source .bashrc
bash: export: '=': not a valid identifier
bash: export: '/usr/local/pig': not a valid identifier
bash: export: '=': not a valid identifier
bash: export: 'PATH:/usr/local/pig/bin': not a valid identifier
bash: export: '=': not a valid identifier
bash: export: '/usr/local/hadoop/conf': not a valid identifier
```

Comment: @KenWhite:
I am beginner and I have tried every possible means, I couldn't succeed that's why I posted it here.

Comment: I see nothing about *every possible means* in your question, and I see nothing that explains what *I couldn't succeed* means. This site is for **specific questions** about **actual problems**. There is nothing **specific** about *I downloaded this thing but it doesn't work.*

Comment: I had put complete problem in the question, but it was not allowing me to post my question. Anyways, I would be highly thankful if you can check it.
I have extracted tar file at location /usr/local/pig-0.15.0
export PIG_HOME = /usr/local/pig-0.15.0
export PATH  =$PIG_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PIG_CLASSPATH = $HADOOP_HOME/conf

There are 2 forms of downloads available.
pig-0.15.0.tar.gz  and pig-0.15.0-src.tar.gz
I have tried both.

Comment: Download only the binary `pig-0.15.0.tar.gz`. And you seemed to have spaces around `=` in the `export` statements.

Comment: @franklinsijo:
I have removed spaces. Now it is not allowing me to run any command on bash. Even when I run ls command it is saying:
bash: ls: No such file or directory

Comment: Your `$PATH` variable is messed up. Open `~/.bashrc`, fix the value and save it. Open a new session then.

Comment: @franklinsijo:
hduser@ubuntu:~$ ~/.bashrc
bash: /home/hduser/.bashrc: Permission denied

Then I tried this, it is not working :(
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742005/bashrc-permission-denied

Comment: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `export` statements added to the `.bashrc` file should not contain whitespaces around `=`

Edit `~/.bashrc`, since the `$PATH` variable is unset, use absolute paths for the executables.

```
/usr/bin/vi ~/.bashrc
```

Add these lines for `Pig` (taken from the comments) to the bashrc file,

```
export PIG_HOME=/usr/local/pig-0.15.0
export PATH=$PIG_HOME/bin:$PATH
```