# Nvm and Node keep going missing upon closing terminal

Tags: node.js, homebrew, nvm

Hoping you can help me figure out this issue!

I just bought a new MacBook and was getting my development environment set up today. I installed XCode, Brew, NVM, and Git. When I installed Git, I had to change it so it was the first in the path so I could avoid using Apple Git, and I think that severely messed things up.

For some reason, nvm was not showing when I was running:
`nvm ls` or `nvm ls-remote`

Yet when I told brew to install nvm, it said it was already installed. OK. Eventually was able to get it sorted out and install node and such.

Fast forward to now, I went to run node in the terminal. Node was not found. Did some research and found that I should not install nvm with homebrew, so I did `brew uninstall nvm` and `brew cleanup` and then installed through the recommend github repository.

I ran the necessary commands and added to my PATH, and when I ran `command -v nvm`, nvm was returned. GREAT. Then I ran the other commands to install Node and I was able to use it, until I closed the terminal.

Now when I reopen the terminal and run node, it returns command not found. `Command -v nvm` does not return anything too.

Please help - it's been such a headache and I can't seem to figure out whats going on. Every solution I'm finding on Stack Overflow works until I close the terminal.

Comment: Add your own answer, which could be upvoted!

Comment: @9000 thank you! I didn't know I could do that!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. The command all NVM guides tell you to run in order to start running node was not properly added to .bashrc.

Use these as a reference if you have the same issue as me:
https://itnext.io/nvm-the-easiest-way-to-switch-node-js-environments-on-your-machine-in-a-flash-17babb7d5f1b
[.bashrc: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742005/bashrc-permission-denied)

Comment: Yes! Basically you just need to add following lines to your .bashrc file:

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

Comment: same issue as above, ran `nvm alias default node` per the link and restarted terminal, seemed to resolve the issue